# How to serve a file over HTTP using Mule?

Tags: mule

Is there a way to create a http access to a file into my resources like creating a website to deliver a file into mule 3.4? If so how or send me some documents on how to build it since im trying to do it and i cant see a way...

This is a test that just do an echo and im searching for a way to send an file from my resources...

```
<flow name="httpWsdlAccess">
    <http:inbound-endpoint name="clientEndpoint" address="${serverName}/file"/>
    <echo-component/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Well im trying to access a file that is included on my resources folder and display it like i display the echo-component using the address "${serverName}/file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `static-resource-handler`:

```
<http:static-resource-handler
      resourceBase="${app.home}/docroot"
      defaultFile="index.html" />
```

in your flow, after the HTTP inbound endpoint.

Comment: ok it made the download the file what is alot more then i had lol, but how to show the file content into a browser? like an WSDL file for instance.

Comment: It should serve all the files in /docroot, independently of their types. What error do you get when you try to HTTP GET a WSDL file?

Comment: I have tried and confirmed the `static-resource-handler` has no trouble serving WSDL files.

Comment: No, it doesnt show the file like it was an wsdl file into the web browser, in my case i use chrome, it sends it for download, i will do some tests and will send a feedback.

Comment: Ok even not serving an wsdl like it was before it works just fine with eclipse and so on :) tks alot!

Comment: David, static resource handler is not allowing mule to send response for image paths with spaces

Comment: @ArunGeorge File a JIRA with MuleSoft.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if anybody is looking this information, the static-resource-handler is explained in the mulesoft documentation here:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-ServingStaticContent%28sinceMule3.2%29